# Selenium Zoom with VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, zoom-sdk

I am looking for a way to control Zoom in chrome with selenium.

I have tried

```
driver.ExecuteScript ("document.body.style.zoom='75%'")
```

This zoom in the actual page, NOT like ctrl & -

```
driver.ExecuteScript "chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5)"
```

- This wont complie

I have no problems with eg. CTRL+a
(for selecting evrything

```
driver.FindElementByTag("body").SendKeys Keys.Control, "a"
```

but it dosn't work for SendKeys Keys.Control, Subtract

Answer (score 0):

The second command doesn't compile because before using it you have to go to the settings page

```
driver.Get('chrome://settings/')
driver.ExecuteScript('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);')
```

Comment: That was really helpful, I just needed to chang ' to " .
Is there a way to open settigs like this
driver.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "chrome://settings/" , it works for http://webpage.com but not for settings or a file:///c:xxxx

Comment: @JesperMartinSchumacher good! but what did you need to change? it is not displayed in the comment

Comment: Not sure what it is called but i changed the single qoute to double qoutes

Comment: @JesperMartinSchumacher `driver.Get("chrome://settings/")` doesn't work?

Comment: YES - but i would like it to open zoom and login

Answer (score 0):

Login Zoom and open multiple pages.

First- dont Zoom before login, it wont click the BTN, heres my final code

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver ' defines outside sub to prevent Crome to close at end of sub
sub loginOpen() 
    driver.start "chrome", "" ' new driver instance
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim First As Boolean
    Dim i As Variant
    First = True
    Set rng = Selection
    With driver
        For Each i In rng
            If First Then
                .Get sURL ' could also just be the login page
                .Window.SetSize 1400, 768
                First = False
                    ' if we need to login
                If Left(.Url, Len(sURL)) <> sURL Or .Url = "" Then
                    .FindElementByName("tbusername").SendKeys ("user")
                    .FindElementByName("tbpassword").SendKeys ("password")
                    .FindElementById("btnlogin").Click
                    .Get ("chrome://settings/")
                    .ExecuteScript ("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.75);")
                    .Get sURL
                End If
            Else
                .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", sURL
                .SwitchToNextWindow
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```